# Postgres how to avoid repetitive if then in select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

What's the easiest way to combine a few columns of a table to set up variables for another query?

I want to avoid constantly repeating the same if then statements in my query

```
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN team_id = away_team_id THEN away_score * 5
WHEN team_id = home_team_id THEN home_score * 5
END AS team_score_times_five, 
CASE
WHEN team_id = away_team_id THEN away_score - 5
WHEN team_id = home_team_id THEN home_score - 5
END AS team_score_minus_five
FROM t1
```

Instead I would rather set up one variable

```
CASE
WHEN team_id = away_team_id THEN away_score
WHEN team_id = home_team_id THEN home_score
END AS team_score
```

and then query it much more cleanly

```
SELECT team_score * 5 AS team_score_times_five, team_score - 5 AS team_score_minus_five FROM t1
```

Comment: That should be possible with SELECT-FROM-SELECT but I forget what that feature is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also try [common table expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
WITH common_table_expression AS (
    SELECT 
        CASE
          WHEN team_id = away_team_id THEN away_score
          WHEN team_id = home_team_id THEN home_score
          END AS team_score
    FROM t1
)
SELECT 
      team_score * 5 AS team_score_times_five
    , team_score - 5 AS team_score_minus_five
FROM common_table_expression
```

CTEs allow you to stack multiple queries that would be nested in ways that tend to be more readable, and more easily modified in the future (depending on the situation) if the business requirement changes.

[This article](https://blog.fishtownanalytics.com/one-analysts-guide-for-going-from-good-to-great-6697e67e37d9) has a great section entitled "Use Common Table Expressions for extremely readable SQL" that makes additional arguments for why you'd want to use a CTE.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a subquery behind `FROM`

```
 SELECT team_score * 5 AS team_score_times_five, 
        team_score - 5 AS team_score_minus_five
 FROM (
   SELECT CASE
     WHEN team_id = away_team_id THEN away_score
     ELSE home_score END AS team_score
   FROM t1
 ) t
```